# How to start new session or INCOGNITO_TAB mode from chrome custom tab Android

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

Using custom chrome tabs in our application and loading website inside but the issue is once logged in with website the session remains the same even kill the application and open it again.is there a way to start a new session or INCOGNITO_TAB from the chrome custom tab please suggest.